# Fiber Type and transceiver model required

Tags: fiber, isp, layer1, service-provider, transceiver

We have an existing 10 G p2p link between our Datacenter ( DC) and Corporate Office ( HQ )with a service provider,  Lets call A

When A did our install they have used a Cienna box on HQ side  , I  guess it is a fiber type converter ( SM to MM fiber ), so we ended up using  MM fiber with a 10G-SR transceiver to our 4500 swicth on HQ side .

On the DC side we still ended up using MM fiber with 10G-SR module .

This circuit was up and running with out issues.

Now we are swicthing to a different Service provide . lets say B.

B says that the hand off will be a SM type , and they are not providing with any Cienna box .

So should we have to use SM fiber with 10G-LR type transceiver to connect to our 4500 on HQ side and also SM fiber with 10G-R type connector on the DC side ?

Is there any way we could reuse the existing MM fiber and 10G-SR modules ??

I am trying to understand how the Service providers run a p2p connection in this case  10G-ELAN , when there are differnt segments involved .  ( in this case .. they have multiple gateways between the circuit from HQ---- gateway1 -- gateway 2 -- DC) and what connector types and fiber types need to be used on each end of the segment .

Please help !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to be concerned with how any ISP runs their network. All that matters to you is what they hand-off. ISP A gave you MM/10G-SR; ISP B is giving you SM/10G-LR. You will need new fiber drops *and* new interface modules.

While the existing MM fiber *might* carry the new signal, passing SM over MM is problematic at the best of times -- and only works over a few meters. The SR modules you have absolutely will not work. They operate at 850nm, while LR operates at 1310nm.

Answer (score 0):

Since ISP A AND ISP B have different cable types, it's clear that you should choose the right fiber type and interface modules provided by ISP B, that is single-mode fiber with single-mode 10G [SFP+ transceivers](http://www.fs.com/c/sfp-plus-transceivers-56), say SFP-10G-LR.